# LocationRequest constructor is marked as internal

Tags: java, android, location

I'm trying to set up location updates in my Android app using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0`, but I'm getting the following error:

> LocationRequest constructor is marked as internal and should not be accessed from apps

My location updates request looks like this:

```
locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
    new LocationRequest()
        .setInterval(5000)
        .setFastestInterval(1000)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY),
    locationCallback,
    null
);
```

I have followed the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#location-request) and the [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/432d3b72b8c058f220416958b444274ddd186abd/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java#L238), which do it the same way. If I'm not supposed to call `new LocationRequest()`, then what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use static method`LocationRequest create ()`.

```
 LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
 locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
 locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
 locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
```

Comment: It is mentioned in doc i guess but not clearly . if you see the [Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/LocationRequest.java) then you will see the constructor is hide . And also constructor is no where mentioned in docs so `create()` is the ultimate solution.

Comment: @ADM Where is it mentioned? The doc says: "Create the location request and set the parameters as shown in this code sample:

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

If you do this you get the annoying warning. The documentation is real crap most of the time.

Comment: Yeah you are right about the Doc. But what in look  up is [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) class . And there is no public constructor listed . And also if you go through the source code you will see than constructor is hide . I can not say much about the Doc but  to me it seems a bit misleading.

Answer (score 15):

**LocationRequest** initialization procedure has changed into latest Google Play Service dependencies ( > 12.0.0). Now you can use its [create()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#create()) method to initialize this. e.g.

```
LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
```