# API error on LocationRequest (Google Maps API)

Tags: android, api, maps

I have an error on implementing Google Maps API.

A small part of the whole source code :

```
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
```

Error :

```
LocationRequest constructor is marked as internal and should not be accessed from apps.
This API has been flagged with a restriction that has not been met.


Examples of API restrictions:
* Method can only be invoked by a subclass
* Method can only be accessed from within the same library (defined by the Gradle library group id)
* Method can only be accessed from tests.

You can add your own API restrictions with the @RestrictTo annotation.
```

I also checked Google Maps API documents on:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest?hl=ko

Thanks.

-Add-
I saw similar question and answers. But when I tried to make `LocationRequest create()` method, the error was still there.

```
    public static LocationRequest create() {
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        return request;
    }

    private void startLocationService() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest().create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LocationRequest constructor is marked as internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488903/locationrequest-constructor-is-marked-as-internal)

Comment: Sir,look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49489018/9130109

Comment: Yes I saw that question and answers. But when I tried to make `LocationRequest create()` method, the error was still there.